# Android orientation changes

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I have one activity which is loading data from webservice.whenever I changed my orientation it load again and again.how can I restrict? I have searched but all of them told to set one orientation like `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`.But I want Both orientation.

anyone can help me please?

Comment: Is there a good reason to create a coupling between the data loading and your activity? if not, move the data loading somewhere else.
application start up? some type of network manager? headless fragment? there are many options and the correct one depends on your specific use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your `onCreate()` method like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    .....
    .....

    if(savedInstanceState == null)
    {
        callWebService();
    }
    else
    {
        // recreate Activity from data saved in onSavedInstanceStae()
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you this? when savedInstance will not be null?

Comment: If savedInstance is null it means it first load your activity and no recent orientation changes... so it is the right solution to you..

Comment: when you rotate, it will not be null

Comment: But it does not show exsiting data which is I got from webservice in first time.What should I do?

Comment: save that data in `onSaveInstanceState()` and recreate it in `onCreate()` if `savedInstanceState` is not null.

Comment: I am getting more data from webservice.and stored it into arrayList.now Should I save that arrayList in onSaveInsatnceState()?

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
<android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
```

to your activity, it will try to retain objects during orientation change. Also, where do you call the method for reloading data from service? You should put it in `onCreate()` so it won't get called on every orientation change when `onResume()`  gets called.  You should also check the documentation here[Android documentation- handling runtime changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)
Maybe you will have to implement `onConfigurationChanged`, depends on your solution.